# Google Adword PHP client library couldn't connect to host

Tags: php, google-ads-api, client-library

Im working on connecting my website to connect to Google Adwords to create ads and campains depending up on the products in my site. I tried connecting by sending direct curl request and parse the received SOAP response. But that is too becoming complex for each request. So i tried using the PHP client library provided in Google Code. But none of the example is working correctly. I changed the user account details in auth.ini file but still on excecuting the example files it says

> **Failed to get authToken. Reason:**
>    **couldn't connect to host**'.

I tried running the scripts in different servers but still getting the same error.

Following is the code to fetch all ads from Google adwords and this is a example file from Client library

```
$path = dirname(__FILE__) . '/../../src';
set_include_path(get_include_path() . PATH_SEPARATOR . $path);

require_once 'Google/Api/Ads/AdWords/Lib/AdWordsUser.php';

try {
  // Get AdWordsUser from credentials in "../auth.ini"
  // relative to the AdWordsUser.php file's directory.
  $user = new AdWordsUser();

  // Log SOAP XML request and response.
  $user->LogDefaults();

  // Get the AdGroupAdService.
  $adGroupAdService = $user->GetAdGroupAdService();

  $adGroupId = (float) '01';

  // Create selector.
  $selector = new Selector();
  $selector->fields = array('Id', 'AdGroupId', 'Status');
  $selector->ordering = array(new OrderBy('Id', 'ASCENDING'));

  // Create predicates.
  $adGroupIdPredicate = new Predicate('AdGroupId', 'IN', array($adGroupId));
  // By default disabled ads aren't returned by the selector. To return them
  // include the DISABLED status in a predicate.
  $statusPredicate =
      new Predicate('Status', 'IN', array('ENABLED', 'PAUSED', 'DISABLED'));
  $selector->predicates = array($adGroupIdPredicate, $statusPredicate);

  // Get all ads.
  $page = $adGroupAdService->get($selector);

  // Display ads.
  if (isset($page->entries)) {
    foreach ($page->entries as $adGroupAd) {
      printf("Ad with id '%s', type '%s', and status '%s' was found.\n",
          $adGroupAd->ad->id, $adGroupAd->ad->AdType, $adGroupAd->status);
    }
  } else {
    print "No ads were found.\n";
  }
} catch (Exception $e) {
    echo 'Inside catch exception';
  print $e->getMessage();
}
```

and in the settings.ini file

> DEFAULT_SERVER =
>   "https://adwords-sandbox.google.com"
>
> `; AUTH_SERVER = "<SERVER>"`

In auth.ini file
My Google account's username and password are set correctly.

Can someone help me in getting this issue fixed.

Thanks

Comment: Please show some of the code you are using. What host are you trying to connect to? Is it reachable?

Answer (score 0):

It's the `AUTH_SERVER` setting, not `DEFAULT_SERVER`, that indicates where authentication requests are being sent. This should be at the bottom of `settings.ini` but is normally commented out so that the default setting of `https://www.google.com` is used. You should check that `AUTH_SERVER` is commented out and that you can connect to `https://www.google.com`.

Comment: yes the auth server setting is commented out and it points to the default server